# oracle query to obtain all major version segmented message values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to crete one sql Oracle query to obtain the major versions of each segmented message values.

I have the next tables with their relationships already filled with example registers:

```
*MESSAGE_TABLE*
ID      NAME
1       hello
2       bye

*SEGMENT_TABLE*
ID      VALUE
1       development
2       production

*MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE*
ID      ID_MESSAGE       ID_SEGMENT        VERSION       VALUE
1       1                1                 2             hello
2       1                1                 1             hi
3       1                2                 1             hi
4       1                null              3             hi
5       1                null              4             hello
6       2                1                 1             bye
7       2                1                 2             good bye
```

MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT is (ID_MESSAGE, ID_SEGMENT, VERSION)

ID_SEGMENT is nullable because null segment indicates default values.

VERSION is a simple number field.

The query has to obtain the major versions of each segmented message values (query results must include the segment value):

Selected result rows from MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE are:

```
ID      ID_MESSAGE       ID_SEGMENT        VERSION       VALUE
1       1                1                 2             hello
3       1                2                 1             hi
5       1                null              4             hello
7       2                1                 2             good bye
```

Query return values should be (same order as the previous selected rows list):

```
NAME(MESSAGE_TABLE)  VALUE (SEGMENT_TABLE)       VALUE (MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE)
hello                development                 hello
hello                production                  hi
hello                null / empty                hello
bye                  development                 good bye
```

The solution is here, thanks to San that did the hard work:

```
WITH  tab AS (SELECT ID, 
                  id_message, 
                  id_segment, 
                  CASE  WHEN lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY id_segmento, id_version) IS NULL 
                          THEN 1 
                        WHEN (nvl(id_segment, -1) != lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY id_segmento, id_version)) 
                          THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                  END change_ind, 
                  version, 
                  VALUE
  FROM MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE)
SELECT b.NAME, nvl(c.VALUE, 'null/empty'), a.VALUE
 FROM tab a 
    JOIN MESSAGE_TABLE b ON (b.ID=a.id_message)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SEGMENT_TABLE c ON (c.ID=a.id_segment)
WHERE change_ind = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain the results?  For instance, id=7 has the same values for message/segment as id=1.  Why is it included?

Comment: Oh, yes. The first fice columns are twice. I am stupid. The example was corrected:
MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT is (ID_MESSAGE, ID_SEGMENT, VERSION)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want something like
you can get first part as

```
WITH MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE(ID,ID_MESSAGE,ID_SEGMENT,VERSION,VALUE) as
(select 1,1,1,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 2,1,1,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 3,1,2,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 4,1,null,3,'hi' from dual union all
  select 5,1,null,4,'hello' from dual union all
  select 6,1,1,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 7,1,1,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 8,1,2,3,'hi' from dual union all
  select 9,1,null,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 10,1,null,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 11,2,1,1,'bye' from dual union all
  select 12,2,1,2,'good bye' from dual)
 ------
 ---End of data
 ------
SELECT id, id_message, id_segment, version, VALUE
  from (
  SELECT ID, 
          id_message, 
          id_segment, 
          CASE  WHEN lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID) IS NULL 
                  THEN 1 
                WHEN (nvl(id_segment, -1) != lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID)) 
                  THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
          END change_ind, 
          version, 
          VALUE
    FROM MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE)
 where change_ind = 1;
```

Output:

```
| ID | ID_MESSAGE | ID_SEGMENT | VERSION |    VALUE |
|----|------------|------------|---------|----------|
|  2 |          1 |          1 |       2 |    hello |
|  3 |          1 |          2 |       1 |       hi |
|  5 |          1 |     (null) |       4 |    hello |
|  7 |          1 |          1 |       2 |    hello |
|  8 |          1 |          2 |       3 |       hi |
| 10 |          1 |     (null) |       2 |    hello |
| 12 |          2 |          1 |       2 | good bye |
```

And second Part as

```
WITH MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE(ID,ID_MESSAGE,ID_SEGMENT,VERSION,VALUE) as
(select 1,1,1,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 2,1,1,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 3,1,2,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 4,1,null,3,'hi' from dual union all
  select 5,1,null,4,'hello' from dual union all
  select 6,1,1,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 7,1,1,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 8,1,2,3,'hi' from dual union all
  select 9,1,null,1,'hi' from dual union all
  select 10,1,null,2,'hello' from dual union all
  select 11,2,1,1,'bye' from dual union all
  select 12,2,1,2,'good bye' from dual),
MESSAGE_TABLE(ID,NAME) AS
(SELECT 1 , 'hello' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'bye' FROM dual),
SEGMENT_TABLE(ID,VALUE) AS
(SELECT 1,'development' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,'production' FROM dual),
 ------
 ---End of data
 ------
  tab AS (SELECT ID, 
                  id_message, 
                  id_segment, 
                  CASE  WHEN lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID) IS NULL 
                          THEN 1 
                        WHEN (nvl(id_segment, -1) != lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID)) 
                          THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                  END change_ind, 
                  version, 
                  VALUE
  FROM MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE)
SELECT b.NAME, nvl(c.VALUE, 'null/empty') C_VALUE, a.VALUE
 FROM tab a 
    JOIN MESSAGE_TABLE b ON (b.ID=a.id_message)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SEGMENT_TABLE c ON (c.ID=a.id_segment)
WHERE change_ind = 1
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Output:

```
|  NAME |     C_VALUE |    VALUE |
|-------|-------------|----------|
| hello | development |    hello |
| hello |  production |       hi |
| hello |  null/empty |    hello |
| hello | development |    hello |
| hello |  production |       hi |
| hello |  null/empty |    hello |
|   bye | development | good bye |
```

So your final query will be :

```
WITH  tab AS (SELECT ID, 
                  id_message, 
                  id_segment, 
                  CASE  WHEN lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID) IS NULL 
                          THEN 1 
                        WHEN (nvl(id_segment, -1) != lead(nvl(id_segment, -1)) over (partition by id_message ORDER BY ID)) 
                          THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                  END change_ind, 
                  version, 
                  VALUE
  FROM MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE)
SELECT b.NAME, nvl(c.VALUE, 'null/empty'), a.VALUE
 FROM tab a 
    JOIN MESSAGE_TABLE b ON (b.ID=a.id_message)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SEGMENT_TABLE c ON (c.ID=a.id_segment)
WHERE change_ind = 1
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Comment: Mmm.... I think this query is too much advanced for me. 
By other way, the example was erroneous, so so sorry. Although if the query is correct for the "erroneous" example, it must be correct for the final more restrictive example. So I try it.

Comment: Yes, now it will work... just try and share your results. There is nothing advance in it, I used analytical function lag() to find at what points id_segment is changing for a particular id_message. Analytical functions are very powerful and useful in such situations...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what you are trying to achieve. Try analytical query.

```
select message_name, segment_value, message_value from (
  select m.name message_name, s.value segment_value, v.value message_value,
         dense_rank() over (partition by v.id_message, v.id_segment order by version desc nulls last) version_rank
  from message_value_table v
       inner join message_table m on v.id_message = m.id
       left outer join segment_table s on v.id_segment = s.id
) where version_rank = 1
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35aa7/10

Comment: Yes, I am convinced that you do not know what I try to achieve. The example was erroneous. The first five columns was twice. I am stupid. The example was corrected: MESSAGE_VALUE_TABLE UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT is (ID_MESSAGE, ID_SEGMENT, VERSION)